# How to Aggregate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2, aggregate

I'm having trouble using aggregation function in swift, I save a number into coredata. However I've been trying to fetch it and organize it by a certain entity. For example there are this 150 Dogs in California, and 60 Cats in California, There are 200 Dogs in Oregon, and 60 Cats in Oregon. I put that into one VC and had people input how many dogs or cats there are in each state. But in the next one I want to be able to Sort by State and total the amount of animals in each state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSExpression class to fetch the aggregated information from CoreData. Here is the example that I've created for your case specifically because I have never did that before and found that interesting ;)

My CoreData model looks like that:

[image]

For the type of Animal I use enum:

```
enum AnimalType: Int {
    case Cat, Dog
}
```

The view controller's code:

```
class AggregationResult {
    let locationName: String
    let animalType: AnimalType
    let count: Int

    init(locationName: String, animalType: AnimalType, count: Int) {
        self.locationName = locationName
        self.animalType = animalType
        self.count = count
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var dataSource: [AggregationResult] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        load()
    }

    private func load() {

        let countExpressionDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
        countExpressionDesc.name = "countAnimals"
        countExpressionDesc.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "type")])
        countExpressionDesc.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Animal")
        request.propertiesToFetch = ["location.name", "type", countExpressionDesc]
        request.propertiesToGroupBy = ["location.name", "type"] // <-- all these properties should be put in 'propertiesToFetch' otherwise we will have crash
        //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location.name == %@", argumentArray: ["Oregon"]) // <-- uncomment to find animals from Oregon only
        request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let results = try! appDelegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

        if let results = results as? [NSDictionary] {

            print("results: \(results)")

            for dict in results {
                if let
                    name = dict["location.name"] as? String,
                    type = dict["type"] as? Int,
                    atype = AnimalType(rawValue: type),
                    count = dict["countAnimals"] as? Int {

                    let ar = AggregationResult(locationName: name, animalType: atype, count: count)
                    dataSource.append(ar)
                }
            }

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let item = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(item.locationName)"
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(item.count) \(item.animalType == .Cat ? "cats" : "dogs")"

        return cell
    }
}
```

The fetching you are interested in is placed in `load` function.
At the end the fetched result I have:

```
results: [{
    countAnimals = 60;
    "location.name" = California;
    type = 0;
}, {
    countAnimals = 150;
    "location.name" = California;
    type = 1;
}, {
    countAnimals = 100;
    "location.name" = Oregon;
    type = 0;
}, {
    countAnimals = 200;
    "location.name" = Oregon;
    type = 1;
}]
```

And table will look like:

[image]

Hope that will help :)

Comment: Just curious, would that enable it to total the dogs amount? Thank you so much by the way.

Comment: If you want to have the total amount of dogs just remove the "location.name" from request's both properties lists (propertiesToFetch, propertiesToGroupBy). The other option is to use NSManagedObjectContext's method [countForFetchRequest:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/countForFetchRequest:error:) instead that is useful for simple aggregations.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry one more question how do you get the double arrow to the relationships?

Comment: That is a [To-Many relationship](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1)

Comment: Sorry, one more quick question I've been trying this out for the past couple weeks but I can't seem to save correctly. How did you save it here, I'm using an entitydescritpion to save it. Is that correct or is there a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "save"? All the data should be already saved in the CoreData's DB.

Comment: Well, I'm saving the animals, states, and qty from user input. I wanted to try it by entering it myself and see the data changing but it won't change like I'm saving it wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with your problem because I have no idea how the saving is organized in your code. I'd recommend to ask that within a separate question where you can describe in more details what you are doing and what goes wrong.